# Zerotier error: 0 join connection failed

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, vpn

Joining my [Zerotier](https://zerotier.com) VPN using

```
sudo zerotier-cli join <id>
```

stopped working for me after a reboot, returning

```
0 join connection failed
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the *zerotier* service is started and running:

```
systemctl status zerotier-one.service
systemctl enable zerotier-one.service # start automatically
systemctl start zerotier-one.service # start once
```

This is also mentioned in their [knowledge base](https://zerotier.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/236322822/Error+Cannot+connect+to+Zerotier+service#Linux).

Comment: Thank u very much, it works for me in archlinux for solve the error: `"Error connecting to the ZeroTier service: connection failed" `